# Convert Varchar in Int ou Int em Varchar (SQL Procedure)

Tags: sql, firebase, firebird, firebase-database

na procedure exitem dois campos(Cod_Fabricante(VARCHAR) e Codigo_Fabricante(INT)), um Varchar e um Int, quando faço um LEFT JOIN pra cruzar as tabelas, ele me da um erro de conversão, tentei usar o CAST e o CONVERT no left join porém ainda deu erro de conversão, alguém sabe dizer se teria outra maneira ou talvez eu tenha usado cast e convert no local errado?? :(

```
BEGIN

DELETE FROM TMP_SALDO_ESTOQUE;

INSERT INTO TMP_SALDO_ESTOQUE
(CODIGO_PRODUTO, TIPO, ENTRADAS, SAIDAS)
SELECT M.CODIGO_PRODUTO, 'E', SUM(M.QTDE) AS ENTRADAS, 0 AS SAIDAS
FROM
     MOVIMENTO_ESTOQUE M
     INNER JOIN LANCAMENTO_ESTOQUE L
       ON M.CODIGO_LANCAMENTO = L.CODIGO
WHERE (M.AFETA_SALDO_ESTOQUE = 'S') AND (L.TIPO = 'E') AND (L.DATA_MOVIMENTO <= :DATA) AND ((:CODIGO_ALMOX = 0) OR (M.CODIGO_ALMOX = :CODIGO_ALMOX))
GROUP BY M.CODIGO_PRODUTO
UNION ALL
SELECT M.CODIGO_PRODUTO, 'S', 0 AS ENTRADAS, SUM(M.QTDE) AS SAIDAS
FROM
     MOVIMENTO_ESTOQUE M
     INNER JOIN LANCAMENTO_ESTOQUE L
       ON M.CODIGO_LANCAMENTO = L.CODIGO
WHERE (M.AFETA_SALDO_ESTOQUE = 'S') AND (L.TIPO = 'S') AND (L.DATA_MOVIMENTO <= :DATA) AND ((:CODIGO_ALMOX = 0) OR (M.CODIGO_ALMOX = :CODIGO_ALMOX))
GROUP BY M.CODIGO_PRODUTO;

FOR
SELECT
  P.CODIGO,
  P.COD_FABRICANTE,
  F.NOME,
  P.DESCRICAO,
  P.CUSTO_MEDIO,
  P.CODIGO_UNIDADE,
  P.CODIGO_GRUPO,
  P.CODIGO_EMBALAGEM,
  P.CODIGO_FORNECEDOR,
  P.TIPO_ITEM,
  P.CURVA_ABC,
  P.LOCALIZACAO,
  P.TIPO_AQUISICAO,
  P.INATIVO,
  P.SERVICO,
  P.DIFER_ICMS,
  G.DESCRICAO AS GRUPO,
  U.SIGLA AS UNIDADE,
  SUM(S.ENTRADAS) AS ENTRADAS,
  SUM(S.SAIDAS) AS SAIDAS,
  P.NCM
FROM
  PRODUTO P LEFT JOIN UNIDADE U
    ON P.CODIGO_UNIDADE = U.CODIGO
  LEFT JOIN FABRICANTE F
    ON P.COD_FABRICANTE = F.CODIGO_FABRICANTE
  LEFT JOIN GRUPO_PRODUTO G
    ON G.CODIGO = P.CODIGO_GRUPO
  LEFT JOIN TMP_SALDO_ESTOQUE S
    ON P.CODIGO = S.CODIGO_PRODUTO
GROUP BY
  P.CODIGO,
  P.COD_FABRICANTE,
  F.NOME,
  P.DESCRICAO,
  P.CUSTO_MEDIO,
  P.CODIGO_UNIDADE,
  P.CODIGO_GRUPO,
  P.CODIGO_EMBALAGEM,
  P.CODIGO_FORNECEDOR,
  P.TIPO_ITEM,
  P.CURVA_ABC,
  P.LOCALIZACAO,
  P.TIPO_AQUISICAO,
  P.INATIVO,
  P.SERVICO,
  P.DIFER_ICMS,
  G.DESCRICAO,
  U.SIGLA,
  P.NCM

  INTO :CODIGO, :COD_FABRICANTE, :DESCRICAO, :CUSTO_MEDIO, :CODIGO_UNIDADE, :CODIGO_GRUPO, :CODIGO_EMBALAGEM, :CODIGO_FORNECEDOR, :TIPO_ITEM, :CURVA_ABC, :LOCALIZACAO, :TIPO_AQUISICAO, :INATIVO, :SERVICO, :DIFER_ICMS, :GRUPO, :UNIDADE, :ENTRADAS, :SAIDAS , :NCM
  DO
  BEGIN
    SUSPEND;
  END
END
```

Comment: qual o erro? onde está a conversão no seu código? não é um erro pq não pode converter (texto para numero)?

Comment: no "from" quando tento converter dessa maneira dá "parsing error":


  LEFT JOIN FABRICANTE F
    ON CAST (P.COD_FABRICANTE AS interger(7)) = F.CODIGO_FABRICANTE

Comment: Olá viva fazer uma comparação de VARCHAR e INT tem tudo para correr mal, se no varchar vier um valor com '10D'...nunca vai converter, o que te aconselho é uniformizar o tipo de dados, tenta arranjar forma de serem do mesmo TIPO.

Comment: Eu tentaria corrigir este modelo , o type "bichado" parece ser o de "produto" , nem deve ter (não publicou as tabelas) FK e deve ter falta de integridade. Concordo com o @Ernesto Casanova.

Answer (score 0):

Testa com o seguinte:

```
SELECT ISNUMERIC(Cod_Fabricante) FROM PRODUTO
```

Vai retornar um ou zero, assim validas se são todas as rows numeric.